# LinkedIn SDK - Login Process forces user to download the native iOS LinkedIn App

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-ios-sdk

The latest LinkedIn SDK requires the user to have the LinkedIn app installed on their devices to login with Linkedin. The authentication process doesn't work otherwise.

We are trying to build an app that creates electronic and customized business cards. The App will use the user's own LinkedIn profile data to fill out the fields within their business card. The user will login into the application by login with LinkedIn.
The LinkedIn API and latest SDK for iOS doesn't allow to login with LinkedIn if the user doesn't have the native LinkedIn iOS app already installed on their devices. The SDK forwards the user to the App Store and forces to download and install LinkedIn app.

This adds complexity to the login process for the user and increase the likelihood that the user will not download the LinkedIn app and so they will not use our app.

We would like understand why and why LinkedIn decided to follow this route that leads developer to user other social networks instead of LinkedIn.

And most important, *What is the process to get login with Linkedin without needing to have the app installed?*

Any advice would be massively helpful for us! Thanks to everybody, we really believe in the power of StackOverflow